# How do people implement UTF-8 in Smalltalk?

Tags: utf-8, smalltalk

I've been doing some preliminary effort implementing `UTF8String` for which I had to address the problems related with messages such as `#size`, `#at:`, `#do:`, etc. Among these there are some for which I could not find a good solution. Examples include `#new:` (class side) and `#at:put:` (instance) because the number of bytes they would need (or use) depends on the actual characters the string will eventually contain.

One idea that one could consider is to allocate additional (unused) null bytes in the tail which would actually not be part of the string and use `#become:` only in those cases were one runs out of null positions. Is this a good (or bad) idea? How should a proper implementation work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to hold the sequence of bytes into an instance variable (a ByteArray) anf thus use a normal pointer based subclass instead of using a variableByteSubclass.

Then the strategy of pre-allocating extra bytes can be easily implemented since you would store effective size into another instance variable. Up to you to tune code complexity/efficiency, memory/speed balance.

The advantage is to avoid messing with other VM primitives like copyReplaceFrom:to:with:startingAt: which can transfer raw encoding from one byte oriented class to another, potentially creating erroneous interpretation of the encodings.

Another advantage is that you don't need to invoke the become: super-power.

Comment: Thanks aka.nice. I had considered this but didn't try (so far) because the new class would not inherit from String and that could create some synchronization issues (both classes evolving together) plus what appears to be a significant duplicate of code (not so sure about this though).

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia ok, could be a problem in Cuis, in this scheme String would need to be an abstract (pointer) class, UTF8String a variableByteSubclass, and ByteString another one (with some well known encoding convention), like in Squeak.

Comment: Oh yes. You are right! I hadn't considered that possibility. I'm not using Cuis but in my system the abstract class `String` is bytes. Your idea for a refactoring makes a lot of sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's best to use UTF8 only for import and export. Internally, use 32 bits for characters.

Comment: I agree. The reason why I'm working on this is to provide some basic facilities for inspection and debugging of UTF-8 sequences that are used for import/export purposes.

Comment: In Python they solved this problem by using UTF-32 internally (basically as Bert suggests), which is a fixed width encoding (although they optimise by dropping unused bytes). See legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393.

Comment: While I agree with Bert, be careful. Even using 32bit for a code point does not guarantee that one 32bit code point is always one character. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to spend the effort, you can do much better than going 32 bit for all characters. Actual texts are either all-ascii (english language, programs), have some non-ascii characters (german, french) or are nearly complete multi-byte. For those with a few non-ascii, you can keep a supporting data structure to help with #at: etc.

Comment: Any suggestion of where you would keep the data structure? The only I can think of is a property (there aren't instance variables in byte objects.) Is this that what you propose?

Comment: Something using the first byte(s) in a special way, I'd say.